# Why won't this code work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a shop. This is my code but it's not working

```
/execute as @a unless entity @s[team=blue,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:2b}]}] unless entity @s[team=blue,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b}]}] unless entity @s[team=blue,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:3b}]}] if entity @s[team=blue,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}]
```

Expanded:

```
/execute as @a
    unless entity @s[team=blue,nbt=
    {
        Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:2b}]
    }]
    unless entity @s[team=blue,nbt=
    {
        Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b}]
    }]
    unless entity @s[team=blue,nbt=
    {
        Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:3b}]
    }]
    if entity @s[team=blue,nbt=
    {
        Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]
    }]
```

What that is supposed to do is give an output when you have at least 4 items. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Well, the first problem is there's now `run <second command>`, so I'm not surprised this command isn't doing anything to begin with.  More importantly though, this isn't how you count how the number of a particular item a player has.

Comment: I didn't have a run command because i was using a comparator from it. How do you count the number of items a player has @MBraedley?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)